# Rails: How to permit a hash with dynamic keys in params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I make a http put request with following parameters:

> {"post"=>{"files"=>{"file1"=>"file_content_1",
>   "file2"=>"file_content_2"}}, "id"=>"4"}

and i need to permit hash array in my code. 
based on [manuals](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) I've tried like these:

```
> params.require(:post).permit(:files) # does not work
> params.require(:post).permit(:files => {}) # does not work, empty hash as result
> params.require(:post).permit! # works, but all params are enabled
```

How to make it correctly?

**UPD1**: file1, file2 - are dynamic keys

Comment: Try params.require(:post).permit(:files => [:file1, :file2])

Comment: It's not an option: file1, file2 are dynamic keys.

Comment: For Rails 5.1 please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44891190/1414100

Answer (score 85, accepted):

### Rails 5.1+

```rb
params.require(:post).permit(:files => {})
```

### Rails 5

```rb
params.require(:post).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:files] = params[:post][:files].permit!
end
```

### Rails 4 and below

```rb
params.require(:post).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:files] = params[:post][:files]
end
```

Comment: FYI in rails 5.0 you'll need to call `permit!` on params[:post][:files] for it to work

Comment: @StephenCorwin can you point to some documentation please?, if that's the case I'll update the answer

Comment: How can this allows to permit and forbid some parameters later on?

Comment: Answer updated to include the latest changes in the Rails API

Answer (score 49):

In rails 5.1.2, this works now:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:files => {})
```

See https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e86524c0c5a26ceec92895c830d1355ae47a7034

Comment: but what if `files` is nested multiple levels deep? e.g. `params['post']['mymodel_attributes']['things']['files']` and `files` can be a hash with any keys?

Comment: The syntax `:files => {}` will allow nested params in `files` to any level.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work for me. It resulted in a literal `{}` in the filtered params. I worked around it though :P Deeply nested input data for StrongParams is not fun to deal with. Improvements in the StrongParameter syntax would be good.

Comment: Hmm, it's working fine for me in rails `5.1.5`. Glad you found a work-around.

Comment: Please note that if you have several permitted parameters in `post`, the hash one (`files` in this case) has to be the last one in the `permit()` list or you'll get a syntax error.

Answer (score 18):

I understand that this is an old post. However, a Google search brought me to this result, and I wanted to share my findings:

Here is an alternative solution that I have found that works (Rails 4):

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({"post"=>{"files"=>{"file1"=>"file_content_1", "file2"=>"file_content_2"}}, "id"=>"4"})
params.require(:post).permit(files: params[:post][:files].keys)
# Returns: {"files"=>{"file1"=>"file_content_1", "file2"=>"file_content_2"}}
```

The difference between this answer and the accepted answer, is that this solution restricts the parameter to only 1 level of dynamic keys. The accepted answer permits multiple depths.

**[Edit] Useful tip from comment**

"Oh, and you need to verify that params[:post][.files] exists otherwise keys will fail"

Comment: Oh, and you need to verify that params[:post][.files] exists otherwise keys will fail

Comment: A neat idea actually (with caveats)

Comment: In the callback you can do whatever you want, the idea is to provide a way to do things, not to allow people to copy paste stuff

Comment: @ChristerFernstrom, I believe if you change the suggested solution from:

`params.require(:post).permit(files: params[:post][:files].keys)`

to

`params.require(:post).permit(files: params[:post].require(:files).keys)`

then verifying that `params[:post][.files]` exists will already happen for you, so you won't ever call `.keys` on `nil`.

Answer (score 6):

Orlando's answer works, but the resulting parameter set returns `false` from the `permitted?` method. Also it's not clear how you would proceed if you were to later have other parameters in the `post` hash that you want included in the result.

Here's another way

```
permitted_params = params.require(:post).permit(:other, :parameters)
permitted_params.merge(params[:post][:files])
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's what we had to do in Rails 5.0.0, hope this helps someone.

```
files = params[:post].delete(:files) if params[:post][:files]
params.require(:post).permit(:id).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:files] = files.permit!
end
```

Comment: Nice approach. Really helped me. Thanks @Garry!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, there was just one attribute which had dynamic keys,

```
def post_params
  marking_keys = Set.new
  params[:post][:marking].keys.collect {|ii| marking_keys.add(ii)}
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, marking: marking_keys.to_a)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary variable to build your permitted list like so:

```
permitted = params.require(:post).permit(:id)
permitted[:post][:files] = params[:post][:files].permit!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get around this:

```
  def post_params
    permit_key_params(params[:post]) do
      params.require(:post)
    end
  end

  def permit_key_params(hash)
    permitted_params = yield
    dynamic_keys = hash.keys
    dynamic_keys.each do |key|
      values = hash.delete(key)
      permitted_params[key] = values if values
    end
    permitted_params
  end
```

This should work for `post: { something: {...}, something_else: {...} }`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it (works for rails 5):

```
  def my_params
    data_params = preset_data_params

    params.require(:my_stuff).permit(
      :some,
      :stuff,
      data: data_params
    )
  end

  def preset_data_params
    return {} unless params[:my_stuff]
    return {} unless params[:my_stuff][:data]

    params[:my_stuff][:data].keys
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Send params as array type like name=date[]**strong text**
      def user_post
        dates = params[:date]
        #render json: { 'response' => params }
        i = 0
        dates.each do |date|
          locations = params['location_'+"#{i}"]
          user_names = params['user_'+"#{i}"]
          currency_rates = params['currency_'+"#{i}"]
          flags = params['flag_'+"#{i}"]
          j = 0
          locations.each do |location|
             User.new(user_name: user_names[j], currency_name: flags[j],
             currency_rate: currency_rates[j], currency_flag: flags[j], location: location).save
            j =+ 1
          end
          i =+ 1
        end
   def
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any of the many proposed answers to work (Rails 5) without either:

1. knowing all the hash keys in advance, or
2. virtually negating the value of strong parameters by allowing arbitrary params.

I'm using this solution.
It uses the standard strong parameters rig to clean up most of the params, 
and the Hash attribute is added back in explicitly.

```
# Assuming:
class MyObject < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :hash_attr as: Hash
  #...
end

# MyObjectsController method to filter params:
def my_object_params
  # capture the hashed attribute value, as a Hash
  hash_attr = params[:my_object] && params[:my_object][:hash_attr] ?
      params[my_object][:hash_attr].to_unsafe_h : {}
  # clean up the params
  safe_params = params.require(:my_object).permit(:attr1, :attr2) # ... etc
  # and add the hashed value back in
  safe_params.to_unsafe_h.merge hash_attr: hash_attr
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, one of many with different ways to update a serialize hash field. I thought I give my version that I accidently found by piecing together some methods. I'll just use my application. This is Rails 7.0.4 and Ruby 3.0. I also use slim templates.

I have a Taxable model that contains semi-persistent tax rates for different Departments.  All items are Sales Tax taxable, but in my case, Liquor adds an additional tax. The Taxable table only has two fields with `tax` being a serialized JSON field.

```rb
create_table "taxables", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date "date"
  t.string "tax"
  ...
end
```

If a Tax is changed or added, the I would add a new record to reflect the change that took place on some date. Any ticket that had a tax in the past would use the record that is the earliest record before the ticket date. Anything new will the new changed record

The Taxable model has a constant that names all taxes that may be used:

```rb
TaxesUsed = %w(sales county federal city liquor)
```

The records would be something like:

```rb
[#<Taxable:0x0000000111c7bfc0
  id: 2,                   
  date: Sun, 01 Jan 2023,  
  tax: {"sales"=>"8.0", "county"=>"2.0", "federal"=>"0.0", "city"=>"0.0", "liquor"=>"3.0"} ...
 #<Taxable:0x0000000111c7b980
  id: 3,                   
  date: Fri, 01 Jan 2021,  
  tax: {"sales"=>"8.0", "county"=>"2.0", "federal"=>"0.0", "city"=>"0.0", "liquor"=>"4.0"}...
]
```

I initially had a kludge that worked, which was creating the hash from some un-permitted parameter and updating the record.  I then found mention of using `form_with` to describe the Tax field and to my surprise it worked!  The form:

```rb
= form_with(model: @taxable) do |form|
 
  div
    = form.label :date, style: "display: block"
    = form.date_field :date

  div
    = form.label :tax, style: "display: block", class:"font-bold"
    = form.fields_for :tax do |tax|
      # @taxable.tax is the existing serialize tax hash or a new default hash
      - @taxable.tax.each do |k,v|
        div.flex.gap-2
          div.w-36.font-bold.text-right = k
          div
            = tax.text_field k, value:v
            
  div[class="#{btn_submit}"]
    = form.submit
```

I had to define a new taxable_parmam that states that :tax is a Hash

```rb
def taxable_params
  params.require(:taxable).permit(:date, :tax => {})
end
```

Submitting the form give me params:

```rb
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "taxable"=>{"date"=>"2021-01-01", "tax"=>{"sales"=>"8.0",
 "county"=>"2.0", "federal"=>"0.0", "city"=>"0.0",
 "liquor"=>"4.0"}}, "commit"=>"Update Taxable", "id"=>"3"}
```

and it works!  I forgot about `form_with` but this is about a simple as you can get just using plain ol Rails.

Update: I forgot that stuff coming from form fields is text. I had to get the params to a new hash, change the float values (percents) and update using the new hash