# Rails 4 Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following dynamic params depending on the line items i am trying to add to an order

```
{"line_item" => {"items"=>{"0"=>{"price"=>"5.75", "name"=>"Item name", "quantity"=>"5"}, "1"=>{"price"=>"3.35", "name"=>"Item name", "quantity"=>"1"}}}
```

In my controller:

```
def lineitems_params
  params.require(:line_item).permit(:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4, :payment_type, :payment_provider).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:items] = params[:line_item][:items]
  end
end
```

I still get the

```
Unpermitted parameters: items
```

in my logs, and it does not update the items. 
How can i solve this?

NOTE: the items hash can have many elements inside.

EDIT:

In my model:

```
serialize :items, Hash
```

Comment: What is the relation between `Item` and `LineTems`?

Comment: item is just a field in the record

Comment: Then you can just give `params.require(:line_item).permit(:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4, :payment_type, :payment_provider,:items => {})`

Comment: It does not work. I updated with the code from the model my question. I still get Unpermitted parameters: items

Comment: Have you tried my updated comment?

Comment: params.require(:line_items).permit! works just fine

Comment: This `params.require(:line_item).permit(:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4, :payment_type, :payment_provider,:items => {})` didn't worked?

Comment: Now i get Unpermitted parameters: price, name, quantity

Comment: params.require(:line_item).permit(:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4, :payment_type, :payment_provider,:items => {})

and Then

params.require(:line_item).permit(:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4, :payment_type, :payment_provider,:items => {:price, :name, :quantity})

Comment: Just give like this `params.require(:line_item).permit(:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4, :payment_type, :payment_provider,{:items => {}})`

Comment: I don't see `:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4, :payment_type, :payment_provider` in your parameters log.Then why you are giving those attributes?

Comment: I receive those i just did not post them here. and they all work fine. This is the only params that is creating a problem.

Comment: Please post your full parameters log.

Comment: Parameters: {"access_token"=>"fd8f25e9d29ca1793c05bbacd0e6aa5279f46387596ebc1c3e09d08e86a2f62365gf", "contentType"=>"application/json", "line_items"=>{"merch_name"=>"Leon Shop", "merch_address"=>"123 street new york", "items"=>{"0"=>{"price"=>"11.50", "name"=>"Item1", "quantity"=>"10"}, "1"=>{"price"=>"3.38", "name"=>"Item2", "quantity"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"price"=>"1.98", "name"=>"Item3", "quantity"=>"2"}}, "payment_type"=>"Credit Card"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
def lineitems_params

params.require(:line_item).permit(:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4, :payment_type, :payment_provider, {:items => {:price, :name, :quantity}})

end
```

**Update**

may be you should just give like this

```
def lineitems_params
  params.require(:line_item).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:items] = params[:line_item][:items]
  end
end
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349887/rails4-how-to-permit-hash-with-dynamic-keys-in-params)**

**Note:** Don't give `params.require(:line_items).permit!` it permits all attributes.

Comment: Now i get this: Unpermitted parameters: price, name, quantity
Unpermitted parameters: price, name, quantity
Unpermitted parameters: price, name, quantity as the hash has 3 elements

Comment: lineitems_controller.rb:171: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end when i tried your updated version. By the way thanks for taking time to help

Comment: @Leon Now please check.

Comment: I have tried that too and it still throws the same error.

Comment: So i tried your solution even before, and what i see is that the record updates but i still get the Unpermitted parameters: items, in my log. I don't know why i still get that though.fow now i will just leave it like this as it works. Not sure why it is still throwing the error.