# Rails: .require.permit() not permitting param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I'm building a backend API with Rails 4.2.4 and came across this problem.

From the client I'm sending to the server a JSON payload of this structure:

```
{
    "Object":{
        "A": {...}
        "B": "..."
        "C": "..."        
    }
}
```

In the `Object` model that I created I have only attributes `B` and `C`, I would like to permit `A` to be sent in (optional), so I did

```
def object_params
    params.required(:object).permit(:A, :B, :C)
end
```

I thought this would do, but when I sent in the actual POST request, the server showed the following message:
`Unpermitted parameter: A`.

Is there anything that I missed? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the actual JSON object you sent to the server?

Comment: Sorry I can't go into the specifics but here's what the server saw (copied from terminal and replaced the variables)
`Parameters: {"object"=>{"A"=>{...}, "B"=>"...", "C"=>"..." }}`

Comment: What are you including in the  `"A"=>{...}` parentheses?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349887/rails4-how-to-permit-hash-with-dynamic-keys-in-params

Comment: Thanks @FlorinIonita, `.tap` works, but is it deprecated (http://apidock.com/rails/Object/tap)?