# Rails permit nested hash attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, attributes, nested, strong-parameters

The controller receives JSON object

```
{
  user: {
    name: "string",
    details: {
      info1: "string",
      info2: []
    }
  }
}
```

During permission controller knows that can permit some defined fields - as name - and hash field details with all nested attributes - also with **arrays**. What is the correct solution for this situation?

**BAD SOLUTIONS**

1. `permit` cannot be used, because I must select user permitted fields
2. `tap do |whitelisted|` cannot be used, because it doesn't make that fields "permit"
3. case below cannot be user, because with arrays doesn't work

   `details_keys = params[:user][:details].keys`

   `params.require(:user).permit(:name, details: details_keys)`

Comment: I'm not sure you're able to pass an empty array. Have you tried making info2 an empty string instead and see if that works?

Comment: Are `info1` and `infor2` defined attributes of the nested object? or are they dynamic?

Comment: Hello, can you explain why it is that you write ```2. `tap do |whitelisted|` cannot be used, because it doesn't make that fields "permit"```

Why is it that it doesn't make fields permit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want to permit a key having an array of **permitted scalar values**, then simply map the key to an empty array:

```
params.permit(key: [])
```

The permitted scalar types are `String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric, TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, DateTime, StringIO, IO, ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile, and Rack::Test::UploadedFile`

So when an array contains some non-scalar values like a hash, then you have to go further by permitting the nested keys too in the array.

Say, you have the following structure:

```
{
  key: [
    {
      attr1: 'string',
      attr2: 10
    },
    {
      attr1: 'another string',
      attr2: 100
    }
  ]
}
```

then the permission goes in this way:

```
params.permit(key: [:attr1, :attr2])
```

---

Now let's assume your case looks like:

```
{
  user: {
    name: "sting",
    details: {
      info1: "string",
      info2: [1, true, :sym] // assume it contains only permitted scalar values
    }
  }
}
```

the permission will be:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, details: [:info1, info2: []])
```

---

To automate this, lets assume `details` has 5 attributes with permitted scalar values and 3 more array attributes that also have only scalar values.

First pluck the 5 non-array keys of `details`:

```
non_array_keys = params[:user][:details].reject { |_, v| v.class == Array }.keys
```

Next the 3 array keys inside `details`:

```
array_keys = params[:user][:details].select { |_, v| v.class == Array }.keys.map { |k| { k => [] } }
```

Now the `details_keys` will be ready by:

```
details_keys = non_array_keys << array_keys
details_keys.flatten!
```

Final permission will look like:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, details: details_keys)
```

If the nested arrays would contain non-scalar values, then I guess you have got enough idea by this point on how to adapt to your changes!

**DISCLAIMER**: this automation is not appreciated because, instead of doing all these, a simple invocation of `params.require(:user).permit!` would suffice. But this marks the `:user` parameters hash and any sub-hash of it as permitted and does not check for permitted scalars, anything is accepted. Extreme care should be taken when using `permit!`, as it will allow all current and future model attributes to be mass-assigned.

For details, I would strongly suggest to look at the [Rails official guide covering Strong Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) in details.

Answer (score 0):

Adding empty array might work. You can switch off validation for nested attributes?! Are you creating dynamic random input fields which you do not control?

Comment: I have a view with a plenty of various field_tags or checkboxes and I want to send only "changed" fields as JSON field in my object

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass dynamic fields?
If that is the case, the following may work

[Configuring strong parameters for dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207766/configuring-strong-parameters-for-dynamic-keys)