# rails permit params setting nested nested array of json to empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I ran into this very interesting problem which i am trying to resolve since last 3-4 hours, where i am not able to permit unknown nested array in json , its setting to empty array

```
params=ActionController::Parameters.new({"id"=>21, "tags"=>{"key"=>[["browser", "Chrome 28.0.1500"], ["browser.name", "Chrome"]]}, "nested_key"=>{"key_2"=>"value_2"}})
```

doing

```
params.permit(:id, tags: {}, nested_key: {})
```

is giving me nested array as `empty("key"=>[])`,

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>21, "tags"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"key"=>[]} permitted: true>, "nested_key"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"key_2"=>"value_2"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

I want all nested elements of array to be permitted since its part of the json.
Can anyone help me with this ?
Please note that nested keys are dynamic which i will not be aware of while permitting.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349887/rails4-how-to-permit-a-hash-with-dynamic-keys-in-params

Comment: this will not help @engineersmnky as i want to permit all the keys as it is, but permit every thing for other key including nested json.